# How to change the session ID without invalidating the current session in JAVA

Tags: java, session

I want to change the session ID without invalidating the session after every request to the server and preserve all the session variable without invalidating it.
As i am using single login to restrict the user from multiple login by changing a flag is_login to true at session creation and to false when session is destroyed with the help of session listener. and after every request i am invalidating the session for generation of new session ID. can i change the session without invalidating it in JAVA.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Its a requirement . Can we do it efficiently to reduce database operations every time i invalidate the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java EE 7 and Servlet API 3.1 (Tomcat 8) you can use [HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#changeSessionId--) to achieve such behaviour.

There is also a listener HttpSessionIdListener which will be invoked after each change.